# Laravel JSON response changes value of associative array key

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've defined a response format for `data` in that Laravel should return in the front-end with the following code:

```
$result1=$spaceRole->pluck('role','space.id')->all();
$resultToReturn=[];
foreach($result1 as $key=>$value){
    $resultToReturn[$key]=array($value);
}
 return $resultToReturn;
```

And the code gives me the following result as expected:

```
 [                       
   850 => [              
     "AUTHORS",          
   ],                    
   766 => [              
     "ADMINISTRATORS",   
   ],                    
   844 => [              
     "ADMINISTRATORS",   
   ],                    
   0 => [                
     "ADMINISTRATORS",   
   ],                    
 ]
```

And i would like to keep the same format in my `json response`.But i the data returned in JSON,the format changes like this :

```
0: ["AUTHORS"]
1: ["ADMINISTRATORS"]
2: ["ADMINISTRATORS"]
3: ["ADMINISTRATORS"]
```

Now the indexes are `0,1,2,3`.Where has `850,844,0 and 766` gone?I would like to use them and not those indexes?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've finally solved the problem.Casting my `reponse` with object type was the solution.

`return (object)$resultToReturn;` to keep my format

Comment: Answer for those who come here later: Some say that you could try and make the keys as strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$result1=$spaceRole->pluck('role','space.id')->all(); 
$resultToReturn=[]; foreach($result1 as $key=>$value){ 
    $resultToReturn[$key]=array($value); 
} 
return json_encode($resultToReturn);
```

Comment: I know,but i don't want to send  a `json` string in the and then call *JSON.parse()*.It's not possible to solve the probleme from `PHP` side in the backend?

Comment: Calling Json.parse is a requirement.

Comment: So you want to say that it's impossible get the job done in the `backend` side?And that issue come only with *integer* keys.With string there is no problem

Comment: In php if u sending any request via api you have to encode it is standard practice.